# Convert HASBYTES function output to CHAR

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, hashbytes

I know that the best data type for storing output of the `HASHBYTES` function is `BINARY/VARBINARY`, but we want to store it as `CHAR` as it is suggested by DataVault best practices, moreover not all tolls support keys of `BINARY` types, for example PowerBI.

So the question is, how to convert it to `CHAR`? When I do simple `CAST/CONVERT` I get different output rather than raw output of `HASHBYTES` function.

```
SELECT  CONVERT(CHAR(32), HASHBYTES('MD5', 'test'))
SELECT  CAST(HASHBYTES('MD5', 'test') AS CHAR(32))
SELECT HASHBYTES('MD5', 'test')
```

Expected value is `098F6BCD4621D373CADE4E832627B4F6` (without `0x`) and actual value is  `kÍF!ÓsÊÞNƒ&'´ö`

Comment: CONVERT(CHAR(32), HASHBYTES('MD5', 'test'), 2)

Comment: `cast` converts between types while you expect a string in a specific format. You can't just use `cast` to get the format you want. You need to specify the desired format, eg using `CONVERT`

Comment: @lpt would you mind to create the answer for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
--convert binary to char without 0x prefix, using style 2
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(32), HASHBYTES('MD5', 'test'), 2);
```